Django Form Processing - how to create a record and add it as ForeignKey
I would like to solve a problem in form handling my views.py.
I would like to process a ModelForm. Instead of letting the user fill the field Field fk_transaction I would like to create a new Record of Transaction and add it as a ForeignKey in the background to the CcountBooking. The Form is displayed correctly in the the template. Also a Transaction is successfully created. However when I want to add and save it to the form in views.py it throws an error telling me that the field is not existing.
Thanks for any help!
My views.py:
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from forms import AccountBookingForm
from models import Transaction


def deposit(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AccountBookingForm(request.POST)
        t = Transaction()
        form.fk_transaction = t
        form.save()
        return render(request, "deposit_success.html", {"form": form})
    else:
        form = AccountBookingForm()
        return render(request, "deposit.html", {"form": form})

My models.py:
class Transaction(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=TR_TYPE_CHOICES, default=DEPOSIT)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices=TR_STATUS_CHOICES, default=DRAFT)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500, default="", blank=True)


class AccountBooking(models.Model):
    fk_bankaccount = models.ForeignKey(
        BankAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    fk_transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=14, decimal_places=2, blank=False)


My forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import AccountBooking

class AccountBookingForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AccountBooking
        fields = ["__all__"]
        exclude = ("fk_transaction",)


Check the form, and create a transaction if the form is valid:
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from forms import AccountBookingForm
from models import Transaction


def deposit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AccountBookingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.fk_transaction = Transaction.objects.create()
            form.save()
            return redirect('name-of-view')
    else:
        form = AccountBookingForm()
    return render(request, 'deposit.html', {'form': form})


Note: While most forms do not process media files, it is probably better to pass request.FILES [Django-doc] to the form anyway, such that if you later add an extra media field, all views that use the form will indeed handle the files properly.



Note: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a redirect [Django-doc]
to implement the Post/Redirect/Get pattern [wiki].
This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
browser.


This is great! Thanks for your answer. Will try this afternoon if it works!

Works like a charm - thanks a lot!
